# TFS 2015 When creating a new External Git Repository Endpoint, should you use the build server service account?

Tags: tfs, endpoints

I'm trying to setup an External Git Endpoint for out TFS 2015 update 4 system. I can't find any documentation on the correct way to set this up. What user name and password should I use?  The build server service account?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Connecting TFS->External Git (or) External Git -> TFS?

Comment: We have groups that have existing projects in our on premise GITLab. For now we will continue to let them use the "external git" but we want to create a CI job in TFS that will pull the source code from the external git.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the build service account if you mean [creating a service connection](http://Service%20connections%20for%20builds%20and%20releases) (`External Git service connection` here).

For [External Git service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#sep-extgit)

- The `username` should be the one which can connect to the external
  Git repository server.
- And the `Password/Token Key` should be the password or access token
  for the specified `username`.

[image]

Comment: If I use my username and password for example in the service connection, wouldn't that then be used for and build activity that uses this endpoint? Wouldn't I just use the same service account that the Build server runs under as long as that Service account has rights to GIT?  What kind of access does that account need to connect to GIT, just read-only, and would it need access to every project that it is going to build?

Comment: @PatDelaney Once you created the services endpoint, the credential will be stored with the endpoint. And when you select the created endpoint (External Git in your scenario) as the build source, the build process will automatically connect to the endpoint with the stored credential to `get sources`. Once the sources downloaded, the other things are the same with internal Git or TFVC in TFS.

Comment: OK so the account that I use for the endpoint connection, just needs to have access to the projects that are in GIT. Since the endpoint can be reused by multiple build definitions that username and password must be authorized to connect to each one of those projects right?

Comment: @PatDelaney Yeah, the username and password is used for connecting to External Git server and get sources from the Git server. So the account (username and password) needs the permissions to access the projects which you want to get sources...

Comment: Is there a way to "Test" the connection, or a log file that I can check to see if the credentials and or path are correct. Or is the Endpoint only called during the build?

Comment: @PatDelaney Once you created the endpoint successfully that means the connection is OK. Yes if you use the endpoint in build, it will call the endpoint first to get sources.

Comment: So I had more time this weekend to experiment... I created the external Git endpoint and the tried to create a build definition for external git. When I queued the build I got the following error: Syncing repository: my GitLab (Git)
Starting clone
failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
Prepare repository failed with exception.
Worker Worker-1285daa9-916c-412d-b5b1-9acee87c1c33 finished running job 1285daa9-916c-412d-b5b1-9acee87c1c33

Comment: The build machine is Windows, do I need to install Git Bash on it and configure the SSH keys on it?

Comment: @PatDelaney You need to install Git on build server, SSH is not necessary.

Comment: So here is a little more about the lab environment. I am running a GITlab vm, it's using https. When I open the web browsers I have to go to advanced and click through the error. I'm guessing that the lack of a certificate is what is causing the error. LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: failed to send request: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally